# Eigenfunction/Eigenvalue component of the wave equation solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wave-equation, eigenfunctions

I have been going through the solution to the Wave equation $\alpha^2U_{xx} = U_{tt}$. The solution goes through separation of variables resulting in the pair of ordinary differential equations $X''(x)=\lambda X(x)$ and $T''(t)=\alpha^2\lambda T(t)$. I can make sense of everything so far. What I struggle with is that after this point Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions start to appear.

My question is why can we not just solve these with the characteristic equation? The physical interpretation of that solution is obviously missing something in this case, I just don't know what other than perhaps different frequencies of the string. However this physical interpretation severely lacks in mathematical rigor that I am looking for. What trivial detail am I missing here?

Comment: You can use the characteristic equation. For example, in the equation $X'' = \lambda X$, setting $X = e^{\mu x} \implies \mu^{2} = \lambda \implies \mu = \pm \sqrt{\lambda}$. You then need to determine whether $\lambda$ is positive, negative or zero by checking if each case and determining if any satisfy your boundary conditions.

Comment: surely then the solution would look like $X(x) = a_1e^{\sqrt\lambda x} + b_1xe^{\sqrt\lambda x}$ and $T(t) = a_2e^{\alpha\sqrt\lambda x} + b_2xe^{\alpha\sqrt\lambda x}$ with $U(x, t) = X(x)T(t)$? this is very different to the result that the literature has: 
$$U(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty {2\over L}\int_{0}^{L}U(x, 0)\sin({n\pi x\over L})\delta x \:\sin({n\pi x\over L})\cos({\alpha n\pi x\over L})$$ Were the integrand is the Eigenvalues and the functional component, the corresponding Eigenfunctions that I am confused about.

Comment: I'm assuming by your solution below you understand what is happening, but in case you don't. If $\lambda = 0$ then $$X = Ax + B$$ If $\lambda > 0$ then $$X = A \cosh(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B \sinh(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$ If $\lambda < 0$ then $$X = A \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)$$ Now apply the boundary conditions as I stated above to see which eigenfunction/value pair satisfies the problem. Also, your sum of exponentials in the comment above is wrong, it should be $X = a_{1} e^{\sqrt{\lambda}x} + b_{1} e^{-\sqrt{\lambda}x}$ in $x$ and $T$ should be a similar form in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ahhhh, I believe understand now. The solution requires that $X(0) = X(L) = 0$. This requires a function of period $2L$. The only solution is then a set of sine waves that have periodicity such that $sin(f(L)) = 0$ for some function of L, it then follows that $f(L) = {n\pi x \over L} for\:n \in \Bbb N$. This gives us a set of values that $\lambda$ can then take, we can then put this set of values in to solve for $T(t)$ and $X(x)$.